# ms access open program and paste telephone number to dial, change program used

Tags: ms-access

I use this code:

```
CreateObject("shell.Application").Open "tel:" & MobilePhone
```

to insert a phone number into our desktop calling program.
The problem is, we had to stop using the app and uninstall it, (3CX desktop app issues) some of the users clicked the button and when a dialogue box opened to select which program to use, they randomly clicked one.
Now that we've reinstalled the program the code is still pointing to the random one that the users clicked.
Is there a way I can change the default program?

I've found instructions for changing the default apps in windows settings but can't find anything for the specific problem. Googling the problem doesn't seem to help as I'm struggling to format the question properly.

Comment: Search google about *Tel protocol*. See this how to change the default app: https://www.bvoip.com/integrations/default-click-to-dial-on-windows-with-tel-protocol

Comment: thank you so much, sorted.